# Where can I have a look at TensorFlow gradient descent main loop?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

(Sorry if this sounds a bit naive) 
I want to have a look at the meat of the [TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/deff101b27e2d3d2d0f68417991e9183bdcd3256/tensorflow/python/training/gradient_descent.py) implementation for GradientDescent - and see for myself how are they handling termination condition, step-size adaptiveness, etc. I traced the code down for `training_ops.apply_gradient_descent` but I can't find the implementation :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TensorFlow `Optimizer` interface, (which `GradientDescentOptimizer` implements) defines a a single step of minimization. Termination conditions or adjusting step size is implemented by the user. In [MNIST for Beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) tutorial, the termination conditions is "stop after 1000" steps which you can see in `for i in range(1000)` loop

`apply_gradient_descent(a,b,c)` is a fused op that multiplies `c` by `b` and adds it to `a`. There are some extra levels of indirection to go from Python wrapper to C++ implementation detailed in [Adding a new op HowTo](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.md), but as a shortcut you can usually find C++ implementation by converting from snake-case and searching for that, so `ApplyGradientDescent` in this case. That leads to implementation in [tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L32)