# TensorFlow: How many gradient steps are made per session.run() call?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

A gradent descent algorithm makes several steps towards the minima.  My question is how many of these steps are performed for every call to sess.run.  To elaborate by example:

I am using a gradient descent algorithm (tf.train.AdamOptimizer) in my network. I have a loop such as this:

```
for epoch in range(100):
    sess.run(ops['optimizer'],
        feed_dict=train_feed_dict
    )
```

This epoch loop runs 100 times.  My question is if a single call to sess.run makes a single small step towards the minima.  OR, is more than one step of the gradent decent made for each epoch?

Comment: I believe this answer may be *the answer*, which is a single call causes a single step for gradient descent.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35728022/2184122  Any corrections or insight appreciated, but I'll assume that that response is correct unless I hear otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ops['optimizer']` is a single call of `tf.train.AdamOptimizer(some_learning_rate).minimize(some_loss)`, then running it will perform exactly one descent step. So there will be 100 steps in your loop.